# Legend of the graph was cut out while exporting via Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with a `matplotlib` created multiline graph with such an external legend that extends outside the boundaries of the figure.

my `code`:

```
dataset = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_axis = np.arange(0,20,5)

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))

A = [1,3,7,8,9]
B = [12,16,14,7,4]
C = [4,17,19,8,6]

plt.plot(dataset,A ,label='A',color='#FFC000',linewidth=3,marker='.',markersize=12,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(dataset,B,label='B',color='#0070C0',linewidth=3,marker='s',markersize=8,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(dataset,C,label='C',color='#404040',linewidth=3,marker='+',markersize=10,linestyle='-')


plt.xticks(dataset)
plt.yticks(y_axis)

plt.xlabel('JobID')
plt.ylabel('Profite')

axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid()

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.20, 0.6),loc='best')


plt.savefig('Figure.jpg',dpi=300)
files.download("Figure.jpg") 

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the legend is chopped out of the exported image while the figure is downloaded using the `savefig` and `download` commands.

You can see the problem more clearly with this [Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Il_d3_oY0n5aSweHEihKCEFWjwu0X2SM?usp=sharing) (in the **last cell**).

Please suggest any solution to fix this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html#legends-and-annotations):

```
# plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.20, 0.6),loc='best')
# plt.savefig('Figure.jpg',dpi=300)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0,0,0.95,1])
plt.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image: tight layout]

Comment: Its works perfectly, thanks for the support. Another small question, How can I change space after(right side) the legend?